# subscripted value is neither a array nor a pointer nor a vector

Tags: arrays, c, dereference

I have the code as below:

```
typedef struct widgest_s{
    int WidgetId;
    void *ItsPage;
}widget;

typedef widget Array_Type_Widget[3];

typedef struct Page_Type_s{
    bool PageActive;
    Array_Type_Widget Widgetlist;
    Array_PageKeyTable PageKeys;
}Page_Type;

void init_main_page(const Page_Type* page)
{

   Page_Type* loc = page;

   update_pagewidget(&loc, &MainPageWidget);
}

void update_pagewidget( void *page, WidgetPtr Ptr)
{
    Page_Type* loc_page = (Page_Type*)page;

    for (int i = 0; i<3; i++)
    {
        (*loc_page->Widgetlist)[i] = Ptr(i);
    }
}
```

I am trying to access the array of widgetlist. Ptr is callback function which returns the
type widget. so while trying the access the widget array, i am Getting the error on line "(*loc_page->Widgetlist)[i] = Ptr(i)"

Comment: You have a superfluous `*` in your code. Write: `loc_page->Widgetlist[i] = ...`.

Comment: Hi Sliepen, with that update the error is gone, but i am not able to update the value inside the widgetlist. Whatever Ptr(i) is returning is not updated

Comment: Shouldn't it be `*Ptr(i)`? Widgetlist is an array of structs not of pointers.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] and read "[ask]". Unfortunately you don't provide a [example], and the code shown has several issues stopping the compiler. Please [edit] your question.

Comment: Ptr is a callback to a function which return widget struc type. Yes, Widgetlist is an array of structs not of pointers, but accessing it using a pointer. So, how to access is the problem now

Answer (score 0):

In this expression

```
*loc_page->Widgetlist
```

the array designator `Widgetlist` is converted to a pointer to its first element. So dereferencing the pointer you get an object of the type `widget` that is not an array. So you may not apply the subscript operator to the object.

It seems you mean

```
loc_page->Widgetlist[i] = Ptr(i);
```